# How to prevent nodes overlapping in cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I have a graph with about 7K nodes and any of the out of the box layout algorithm always results in overlapping nodes. I've seen cystoscope-no-overlap for cytoscape.js; is there something similar for the desktop?

I could be unaware of some basic functionality in cytoscape desktop too - I'm still new to the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options for getting your layouts just right:

1. Layout Tools: Here you can use scale to create space evenly between all nodes
2. Layout Settings: Here you can tune the parameters of any of the open source layout algorithms to adjust how crowded or sparse your nodes end up
3. Try the yFiles layouts, which appear to have an extract step to minimize overlaps